# How to retrieve the "Title" field from Lightroom on a JPEG using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, exif, photography, lightroom

I am putting Title & Caption onto my photos in Lightroom, then exporting them as JPEG. Later in my workflow I am using ImageMagick (through a .NET library) to process these images. I can retrieve the EXIF Profile and get the caption from the "ImageDescription" tag, but I can't seem to find the Title in there anywhere. Does anyone know where Lightroom puts the Title into the image data?

I looked through all 49 EXIF values, but none contained the string I put in for Title. Caption was present though, along with everything else I expected (lens info, date, camera, copyright).

Comment: In Imagemagick, you can store both the title and caption. The caption can be stored as a caption and the title can be stored as a label. For example, `convert image.suffix -set caption:"So text for the caption" image.suffix`

Comment: They can be retrieved once stored using %c for caption and %l for label.  For example `convert image.suffix -format "%c" info:`

Comment: Try setting the title to some unique and unlikely word, like `MUPPETRY` in Lightroom, then export the file and grep for `MUPPETRY` In the file to see if it is in there. Also try `exiftool -v -v -v YOURFILE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I grabbed an image and added a title (`MUPPETRY`) and description (`PUPPETRY`) in **Adobe Lightroom** using the metadata panel like this and then exported as JPEG:

[image]

In case you are wondering, I chose silly names for near certain uniqueness.

---

It seems that **Lightroom** puts the title and caption in the IPTC section. You can tell that by using:

```
exiftool -G0 export.jpg | grep UPPETRY    
[EXIF]          Image Description               : PUPPETRY
[IPTC]          Object Name                     : MUPPETRY
[IPTC]          Caption-Abstract                : PUPPETRY
[XMP]           Title                           : MUPPETRY
[XMP]           Description                     : PUPPETRY
```

On Windows, use `FINDSTR` instead of `grep`.

You can extract them with `exiftool` like this:

```
exiftool -IPTC:Caption-Abstract -IPTC:ObjectName export.jpg
Caption-Abstract                : PUPPETRY
Object Name                     : MUPPETRY
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
exiftool -Title -Description export.jpg 
Title                           : MUPPETRY
Description                     : PUPPETRY
```

Or, if you just want the value in a `bash` variable, use the `-short` option like this:

```
title=$(exiftool -s3 -Title export.jpg)
echo $title
MUPPETRY
```

---

If you want to see IPTC metadata with **ImageMagick**, use this to discover all the data:

```
magick export.jpg IPTCTEXT:-   
        
1#90#City="&#27;%G"
2#0="&#0;&#4;"
2#5#Image Name="MUPPETRY"
2#120#Caption="PUPPETRY"
```

You can then see the field numbers of the ones you want and extract just those:

```
identify -format "%[IPTC:2:5]" export.jpg
MUPPETRY

identify -format "%[IPTC:2:120]" export.jpg
PUPPETRY
```